# Extracting string from a href tag with Python 2.7x

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am currently using Beautifulsoup4 to extract 'a href' tags from a HTML page. I am using the find_all query in Beautifulsoup4 and it's working fine and returning the 'a href' tags I'm looking for. An example of what is returned is below:

```
"<a href="manage/foldercontent.html?folder=Pictures" style="background-image: url(shares/Pictures/DefaultPicture.png)" target="content_window" title="Vaya al recurso compartido Pictures">Pictures</a>"
```

What I'm looking to now do however is simply extract `"<a href="manage/foldercontent.html?folder=Pictures"` as opposed to the full content returned as above.

My code is below:

```
req = urllib2.Request(example_url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), from_encoding=response.info().getparam('charset'))
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    # The below 'if' is to filter out only relevant 'a href' tags
    if "foldercontent.html?folder" in link['href']: 
        print link
```

Is this possible with modifying what I search for or would I have to run a regex across my returned string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for link in soup.select('a[href*="foldercontent.html?folder"]'):
```

The `[<attribute>*="<substring>"]` syntax matches any attribute value that contains the substring.

Note that you get `Element` objects returned, not strings; if you need to parse out specific information from the matched URL, you could parse the `link['href']` value with the [`urlparse` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) to get just the URL path, or just the query string, or parse the query string into its constituent parts.